# Why comboboxitem show strange blue blank even I rewrite it?

Tags: wpf

I rewrite a `ComboBoxItem` by custom control with these code:

XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,15"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" >
                        <Label Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Padding="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                        </Label>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dbdbdb"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#c9c8c9"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SealBase
{      
    public class SComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem
    {
        static SComboBoxItem()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SComboBoxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SComboBoxItem)));
        }
    }
}
```

Well, and then I make a demo as this:

```
<ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,0,10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Name="FontFaimlyCB" Height="50" Width="250">
            <Seal:SComboBoxItem>123</Seal:SComboBoxItem>
            <Seal:SComboBoxItem>123</Seal:SComboBoxItem>
            <Seal:SComboBoxItem>123</Seal:SComboBoxItem>
            <Seal:SComboBoxItem>123</Seal:SComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

All is OK as below:
[image]

However, after I change the code of the demo as this:

```
<ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,0,10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Name="FontFaimlyCB" Height="50" Width="250" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Seal:SListBoxItem Content="{Binding}">
                    </Seal:SListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

And now it turns out to be something wrong:
[image]

The demo occurs a strange blue blank. I don't know why it turns out to be this. I doubt it is the problem of the `ComboBox` control. But after I rewrite a brand new one inherits the `ComboBox` with the custom control. The problem still here.

What's wrong with this? And how can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with this?

The element in the `ItemTemplate` automatically gets wrapped in a `ComboBoxItem` container.

> And how can I solve it?

If you want to render a `SListBoxItem` for each item, you could create a custom `ComboBox` class that overrides the `GetContainerForItemOverride()` method:

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return (item is SListBoxItem);
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new SListBoxItem();
    }
}
```